# MySQL get count of items using RIGHT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need to collect all posts created by one user and get count of people who joined them.

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT ads.id, ads.title, sign_ups.user_id
FROM sign_ups RIGHT JOIN ads ON ads.id = sign_ups.ad_id
WHERE advertiser_id=1
```

And the output is:

```
id      title                  user_id
1      Something                  1
2      something else             2
3      another title             NULL
1      Something                  2
```

But I want:

```
id      title               total
1      Something              2
2      something else         1
3      another title          0
```

But I want:

```
id      title               total
1      Something              2
2      something else         1
3      another title          0
```

So I have tried this:

```
SELECT ads.id, ads.title, count(sign_ups.user_id) AS total
FROM sign_ups
RIGHT JOIN ads ON ads.id = sign_ups.ad_id
WHERE advertiser_id =1
```

But the output doesn't include all `title` fields which has none followed user. So result looks like this:

```
id      title                  total
1      Something                 2
2      something else            1
```

Want to ask, how to change my query to get all wanted records.

Thanks!

Comment: `IFNULL` and `GROUP BY` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ads.id, ads.title, count(sign_ups.user_id) AS total
FROM sign_ups
RIGHT JOIN ads ON ads.id = sign_ups.ad_id
WHERE advertiser_id=1 AND sign_ups.user_id IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ads.id, ads.title, 0 AS total
FROM sign_ups
RIGHT JOIN ads ON ads.id = sign_ups.ad_id
WHERE advertiser_id=1 AND sign_ups.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "ifnull" that should make sure that even those with no user ids should show up.  I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I'd be happy to help.

```
SELECT ads.id, ads.title, ifnull(count(sign_ups.user_id), 0) AS total
FROM sign_ups
RIGHT JOIN ads ON ads.id = sign_ups.ad_id
WHERE advertiser_id =1
```

Here's an article about IFNULL(): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull